# Liquid: Converting comma separated currency to dot separated

Tags: formatting, shopify, liquid

the price-decimals on my store are by default separated by comma (e.g. 6,99 €).
Now I need to convert them into dot separated version without the currency icon (e.g. 6.99).

Does anyone know how to do this with liquid filters? I'm stuck! I don't want to change the base-formatting settings in the store.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use the money filter itself to change the money format in the Liquid output.  Is Javascript a viable option for you?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
{{ 145 | money_without_currency | replace:',','.' }}
```

https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/money-filters

Comment: Did you test this with values greater than 100000 to make sure that the money filter isn't printing a thousands separator?  If so, that could cause unexpected problems if any items go over 1000 currency-units (possibly not a problem with Euro, but could be a problem for anyone selling expensive items or selling in a lower-value currency)

Comment: Something a bit safer would be: `{{ 145 | money_without_currency | replace:',','x'  | replace:'.',',' | replace:'x','.' }}`